# Define colors using xcolor-material

Tags: color

**Problem:**

I am trying to define colors using the `xcolor-material` package but receive an error when compiling.

**Error message:**

> Paragraph ended before \XC@definec@lor was complete.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{kvoptions}
\usepackage{xcolor-material}

% Material Colors
\definecolor{MaterialOrange}[cmyk]{orange}

\begin{document}

{\color{MaterialOrange}Hello}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try with `\definecolor{MaterialOrange}{named}{orange}`

Comment: You are aware that `\color{MaterialOrange}Hello` is not really useful -- even for this MWE ... if used otherwise it will cause color bleeding into the rest of the document

Comment: @samcarter But according to the manual you need to load the cmyk option?

Comment: @kexxcream Where does it say this? I only found 10 occurrences of `cmyk` in the  `xcolor-material` documentation and none said something like this.

Comment: @kexxcream: `cmyk` option wouldn't work even for the normal `xcolor` `\definecolor` command.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It is the `\definecolor` from `xcolor` we are talking about. As far as I can see, `xcolor-material` more or less just defines additional colours with a bit of naming scheme ...

Comment: @samcarter: Yes, I see -- I thought `xcolor-material` would add a redefined `\definecolor`. Well, no example in `xcolor` manual reveals that `cmyk` would work with a named color in conjunction with `\definecolor`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer With another syntax it works, like `\definecolor[named]{Black}{cmyk}{0,0,0,1}`, but this does not fit the question, as it does not have the cmyk values.

Comment: @samcarter: Yes, I know, but in this case `{0,0,0,1}` is no named colour. I think `named` is just a modifier internally and `cmyk` lets `xcolor` interpret `{0,0,0,1}` (which is black, of course)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`orange` is predefined, you can simply use it as `{\color{orange}Hello}` without any color definitions. Otherwise, use the form `\definecolor{MaterialOrange}{named}{orange}` as noted also by @samcarter or using the color value and model given in the manual. Finally, you should embrace the colored portion between two `{}`, otherwise, the whole document will take the defined color.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{kvoptions}
\usepackage{xcolor-material}

% Material Colors
%\definecolor{MaterialOrange}{named}{orange}  % This or
%\definecolor{MaterialOrange}{HTML}{FF8000}   % this or
\definecolor{MaterialOrange}{cmyk}{0,0.5,1,0} % this

\begin{document}

{\color{MaterialOrange}Hello} and normal text ..

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just want to understand this correctly, if I use `\definecolor{MaterialOrange}{named}{orange}` and then `{\color{MaterialOrange}Hello}`, would it apply the cmyk value of that material color?

Comment: @kexxcream: Both `orange` and `MaterialOrange` are predefined colors and are different. Here, you copied the values of `orange` into `MaterialOrange`, they are now the same, the original cmyk of `orange` is now applied.

Comment: Thanks, so basically one wouldn't need to define colors but instead just use them right out of the box like: `{\color{MaterialOrange}Hello}` - and this would apply the cmyk color, correct?

Comment: Yes, too many colors are predefined in the manual, but take care of the differences as I mentioned above (`orange != MaterialOrange`).